# Relation between $E_o$ and $B_o$ in EM waves

Tags: waves

I was studying EM Waves and had a doubt. Since we know that EM Waves travel with speed:

$$\frac{c}{\sqrt{\epsilon_r\mu_r}}$$

in a medium with relative permittivity $\epsilon_r$ and relative permeability $\mu_r$, will the relation between $E_o$ and $B_o$ be:

$$E_o = B_o  \frac{c}{\sqrt{\epsilon_r\mu_r}}$$

or will it simply be:

$$E_o = B_o c$$

irrespective of the medium the EM wave is travelling in?

Comment: This relation Is not true inside medium. For example in conductors the relation is far more complex

Comment: Ah I see thank you!